# How do I avoid returning to a parent activity performing a background task before finishing itself?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

My app has a launcher activity that looks at the intent used to call it and calls one of many activities based on the intent (let's call the child activity B). The launcher activity also launches an AsyncTask to do some clean up in SharedPreferences in the background. Once that background task finishes, the launcher activity calls `finish()` to terminate itself.

If the background task is still not finished when activity B terminates, I want to avoid returning to the launcher activity. How can I do that?

I am thinking of using `android:noHistory="true"` in the definition of the activity in the manifest. However, the [description](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) of noHistory says:
"Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen". So I am afraid that the activity might be terminated before it finishes running its background task.

Is my background task guaranteed to be allowed to run to completion? Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make is simple. Start a background task in your [application instance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and clean-up preferences there. This will allow you to finish your "dispatcher" activity immediately after it started a next required activity.

Regarding excluding the activity from the back stack. There are two options. You can either define "dispatcher" activity with `android:noHistory="true"` in manifest file, or start "dispatcher" activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`. Both options will exclude the activity from back stack.

Also, if "dispatcher" activity is in background, Android might decide to destroy it at any time. This might lead to unexpected results. With proposed soliton you have no such issue either.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's a good suggestion, but unless the user specifically terminates it, the application can stay loaded even after the user quits it, meaning that Application#onCreate is not called when the app is restarted. So the clean up task could be called very infrequently.

Comment: I meant you call cleanup task from your dispatcher activity as you do it now, but the task runs in the Application. That's why you can finish activity immediately. You don't use Application.onCreate() at all.